# How to save startup projects configuration in VS 2019?

Tags: visual-studio-2019

We can set the multiple startup projects for a solution, if later we need to run only one project for X reason, the previous configuration is lost, and we have to manually select all the startup projects again. Is there any way to save that configuration or a workaround ?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

One option is that you can create a new solution for the situation where you want to run only the one project for X reason.

The new solution file can co-exist next to your current one just fine, but if you have any scripts running that expect only one solution you might have to adjust them.

For example, `dotnet run` might need to be changed to `dotnet run original.sln`

I use this technique for the case where I want to run unit tests against a library but the main solution has multiple target framework projects in it. This setup makes the unit test runners unhappy, but having a second solution file allows me to setup solution level configurations. In my case it means reducing what projects are in the solution and changing the startup project.

Comment: The thing is that we work in the solution, so sometimes we need to run one project and sometimes multiple. If we create a new solution, we would need to migrate changes every time we make them, right?

Comment: No, you wouldn't need to migrate changes usually. The solution just loads the same project files (for the selected projects) The only file you'd need to migrate changes to is the .sln files themselves, all project and code files referenced from the solutions are literally the same ones. You can see how I did it for my new open source library here: https://github.com/yellowstonegames/SquidLibSharp/tree/master/code